# Moving a 2D object in Unity. Confusing co-ordinate system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object, which is the menu. It is 3 times the width of the screen.

I'm attempting to move the menu one width of the screen.

So far I am using:

```
float xPos = settingsMenu.transform.position.x;
xPos = xPos + Screen.width;
Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(xPos, 0, 0);
settingsMenu.transform.position = newPos;
```

This moves the menu far too far, absolutely miles off screen.

I understand the screen width is dependent on the resolution of the screen of the player, but the settingsMenu.transform.position.x seems completely arbitrary. When I move the settingsMenu object exactly one screen width, then settingsMenu.transform.position.x is 23.32395.

Where does this number come from and how can I move the object correctly so it moves exactly one screen's width?

Answer (score 0):

To get the screen width in world units you can use this method:

```
private Vector2 GetScreenInUnits(Camera camera, float distanceFromCamera)
{
    Vector3 min = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, distanceFromCamera));
    Vector3 max = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, distanceFromCamera));
    min = camera.transform.InverseTransformPoint(min);
    max = camera.transform.InverseTransformPoint(max);
    return max - min;
}
```

You will need to pass the camera for which you want to measure and the distance between the camera and the object you intend to move. Say for the settings menu you can get the distance to the main camera using `float distance = Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, settingsMenu.transform.position);`. So the code will look something like:

```
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position, settingsMenu.transform.position);
    Vector2 screen = GetScreenInUnits(Camera.main, distance);
    Vector3 delta = new Vector3(screen.x, 0, 0);
    settingsMenu.transform.position += delta;
```